# How to get 10 per line -leap years

Tags: java

Please help with formatting my output.

I have been asked to "Write a program that displays all the leap years, ten per line, in the twenty-first century (from 2001 to 2100), separated by exactly one space".

Although I get the right results, it's not in the required format.

Thanks in advance

```
    public class Leapyear {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //declare variabls;
     int year;
     int count=1;
     int yearsperline = 10;
     //loop
     for(year=2001;2001<=2100;year++){
         if((year%4==0 && year%100!=0) || (year%400==0))
             System.out.print(year+",");
           if ( year ==2100)
               break;
        while (count%10==0)
        System.out.println();
     }
     }    

   }
```

Comment: What output do you currently get? Can you give an example of current output vs desired output?

Comment: `2001<=2100` is exactly the same as `true`. You can replace that with `year <= 2100` and get rid of the explicit break later.

Comment: You don't seem to be incrementing `count` anywhere, so your condition `count%10==0` will never be true.

Comment: Perhaps using `" "` instead of `","` might meet the criteria of "separated by exactly one space".

Comment: if years only range from 2001 to 2100, you only need to check `year % 4 == 0`

Comment: This might help: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/gregoriancalendar_isleapyear.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like this:

```
//declare variables;
final int YEARS_PER_LINE = 10;
final int START_YEAR = 2001;
//loop
for(int year = START_YEAR; year <= 2100; year++){
    System.out.print(year);

    if((year - START_YEAR) % YEARS_PER_LINE == (YEARS_PER_LINE - 1)) {
        System.out.println();
    } else {
        System.out.print(",");
    }
}
```

Comment: This would be an infinite loop.
Edit: Not anymore, condition have fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
public class LeapYear
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // declare variables
        final int startYear = 2001;
        final int endYear = 2100;
        final int yearsPerLine = 10;

        // loop
        for (int year = startYear, count = 0; year <= endYear; year++)
        {
            if ((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0))
            {
                if (count % yearsPerLine != 0)
                    System.out.print(" ");
                else if (count > 0 && count % yearsPerLine == 0)
                    System.out.println();

                System.out.print(year);
                ++count;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    int startFromYear = 2001;
    int stopAtYear = 2100;
    int count = 0;

    for(int i = startFromYear; i <= stopAtYear; i++){
        if((i % 4 == 0 && i % 100 != 0)||(i % 400 == 0)){
            System.out.print(i + " ");
            count++;
            if(count % 10 ==0)
                System.out.println();
       }    

  }
```

Comment: Some words of explanation usually are appreciated on stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

100% correct! and easy to understand.

```
public class LeapYears
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int count = 0;
        for(int i = 2001; i <= 2100; i++)
        {
            if ((i % 4 == 0 && i % 100 != 0)||(i % 400 == 0))
            {   
                count++;
                //if count is 10 then start a new line. 
                if(count % 10 == 0)
                {
                    System.out.println(i);
                }   
                //if count is smaller 10 then in the same line 
                else
                {
                    System.out.print(i + " ");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it is 100% correct? Plot twist: 2100 is not a leap year.